# Erro Traceback (most recent call last) em uso de API Web

Tags: python, json

Olá, estou aprendendo Python e estou com um erro, estou utilizando a API WEB do BNDES, estou voltando a consulta em formato JSON, mas não consigo selecionar somente o campo "data". Consigo fazer toda a parte de pegar a autorização e key de acesso, e consigo retornar o JSON da pesquisa por completo, mas não o campo "data" somente, tem como eu fazer isso? Sempre que tento recebo o erro

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/main.py", line 59, in 
> print('Data: '.format(retorno2['data']))

````
import requests

print('')
print('Consultar Moeda: ')
print('')

url = 'https://apis-gateway-h.bndes.gov.br/token'
urlmoeda = 'https://apis-gateway-h.bndes.gov.br/moedascontratuais/v1/servicoListaCotacoes'

user_data = {
       "grant_type": "client_credentials",
       "Authorization": "",
       "client_id": "",
       "client_secret": ""
}

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, params=user_data )

print(response.status_code)
print(response.reason)

retorno = response.json()

print('Token: {}'.format(retorno['access_token']))
print('Scope: {}'.format(retorno['scope']))
print('Token_Type: {}'.format(retorno['token_type']))
print('Tempo: {}'.format(retorno['expires_in']))

# print('Bearer ' + format(retorno['access_token']))

headers2 = {
   'Content-type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': ''
   # 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +format(['access_token'])
   }

dados_moeda = {
   "serie": "143",
   "sigla": "SELIC ACUM. D-2",
   "dataInicio": "20230222",
   "dataFim": "20230222"
   }


response2 = requests.get(url=urlmoeda, headers=headers2, params=dados_moeda)

print(response2.status_code)
print(response2.json())

retorno2 = response2.json()

print('Data: '.format(retorno2['data'])) ```
````

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dessa forma, você acessa o primeiro dicionário da lista 'listaCotacaoMoeda' com o índice [0] e então acessa a chave 'data' desse dicionário para imprimir a data correta.

```
print('Data: {}'.format(retorno2['listaCotacaoMoeda'][0]['data']))
```

Comment: Opa, tudo certo? Então, tentei usar esse mesmo raciocínio e não funcionou também, o erro que volta é:

{'erro': False, 'listaCotacaoMoeda': [{'data': '22/02/2023', 'valor': '2,720648'}]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/main.py", line 58, in <module>
    print('Data: {}'.format(retorno2['data']))
KeyError: 'data'

Comment: Consegue disponibilizar o Json?

Comment: O Json, estava na linha ali, é esse aqui o retorno que ele tem quando eu chamo o JSON por inteiro:

{'erro': False, 'listaCotacaoMoeda': [{'data': '22/02/2023', 'valor': '2,720648'}]}

Comment: Tenta assim: print('Data: {}'.format(retorno2['listaCotacaoMoeda'][0]['data']))

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda André!